# regressions with common domain: upper bound on r squared

Tags: regression, r-squared

Heres a conjecture I'm struggling to prove / disprove:

> Let $X \in \mathcal{R}^{N \times a}$ represent a set of $N$ observations, each having $a$ features.  Paired with each observation $x_i$ are two observations $y_{i, \alpha}, y_{i, \beta} \in \mathcal{R}^b$.  Let $Y_\alpha , Y_\beta \in \mathcal{R}^{N \times b}$ represent these observations.  We wish to show:
>
> $r^2 \leq \frac{r^2_\alpha + r^2_\beta}{2}$
>
> where $r_\alpha^2$ is associated with the mapping from $X$ to $Y_\alpha$, $r_\beta^2$ is defined similarly and, $r^2$ is associated with the mapping from $X$ to the union of all observations of $y$.  Namely, in this union problem one maps from design matrix $X' = \begin{bmatrix} X \\ X \end{bmatrix}$ to $Y'= \begin{bmatrix} Y_\alpha \\ Y_\beta \end{bmatrix}$.

Note: $r^2$ are the multivariate coefficients of determination associated with the minimum mean squared error mappings:

$r_\alpha^2 = 1 - \frac{Tr(\mathcal{E_\alpha}^T \mathcal{E_\alpha}) }{Tr(\Sigma_\alpha)}$,

where $\Sigma_\alpha$ is the covariance of $Y_\alpha$ and $\mathcal{E_\alpha}$ is a matrix of regression errors:

$\mathcal{E_\alpha} = Y_\alpha - X X^\dagger Y_\alpha$

for pseudo-inverse $X^\dagger$.

Comment: Two comments which may inspire some solutions: (1) because the domain of the regressions is constant they all have the same pseudo-inverse. therefor the min MSE mapping of the union of Y_\alpha Y_\beta equals the average of mappings to each. (2) I've simulated this and it seems to hold on a bunch of randomly drawn datasets

Comment: How, at the end, did the number of observations suddenly double from $N$ to $2N$?  The previous description concerned data in $\mathbb{R}^{N\times (a+2b)}.$

Comment: the final regression considers a 'union' of all observation pairs $(x_i, y_{i,j})$.  Because each $x_i$ has two associated $y_{i,j}$ one can describe this union via $X'$ and $Y'$. Note that $X'$ has repeated rows to keep correspondence with $Y'$'s rows.  I hope this helps!

Comment: It's what I guessed, but its statistical meaning is both suspect and at odds with your previous description.  It would help to clarify that the $\alpha$ and $\beta$ observations are considered some form of *replication* for the $n$ original independent variables.  This also raises questions concerning the statistical validity of your model, so if you're hoping to apply this to any actual data you will need to consider that issue.

Comment: What you want to consider carefully is the variance model, because the repeated measures will not be independent.  The focus on r-squared indicates this isn't being accounted for.